# Возвращаемый тип оператора ->

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Почему мне не выдает ошибок при определении, ведь оператор -> должен возвращать указатель или класс, у которого есть -> ?

```
struct X {
    int operator -> () {
        return 42;
    }
};


int main() {
    X x;
    x.operator->();
//    x->(); // error
}
```

Comment: Ничего такого он не должен, однако возвращение чего-то, не имеющего `->` делает невозможным вызов этого оператора как оператора (а вызов как функции все равно будет работать).

Comment: @VTT The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @nick_n_a о чём вы вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт не устанавливает требований на тип, возвращаемый перегруженным оператором `->`. Однако возвращение чего-то, не имеющего `->`, делает невозможным вызов этого оператора как оператора (а вызов как функции все равно будет работать)

> **16.5.6 Class member access [over.ref]**
>   1 `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no parameters. It implements the class member access syntax that uses `->`.
>   *postfix-expression -> template opt id-expression*
>   *postfix-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name*
>   An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object x of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это не эквивалентно The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded ? Так как последнее накладывает ограничение на возвращаемый тип, а ваша цитата нет

Comment: @jack Да, это совсем не эквивалентно. В стандарте только указывается, что эта функция должна быть без аргументов, не устанавливая никаких ограничений на тип возвращаемого значения.